# Problem evaluating Wolfram Symbolic Integration Result

Tags: integration, symbolic-computation

****** Note: In response to the comment below, I've modified the problem ******

I'm trying to evaluate the following indefinite integral

$$
\Large\int x^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\frac{K}{x}\Big[(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2\Bigr]}
$$

where $ K,a,b >0$ and $c\ge 0$. For the curious, this models the transient dispersion of a pollutant with a time dependent mass source ($x$ is really a time variable)

Wolfram Alpha is unable to integrate this particular form

[image]

Fair enough. I'm willing to do some legwork, so I recast the integral as

$$
\Large\int x^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\Big[Ax+B+\frac{C}{x}\Bigr]}
=e^{-B}\Large\int x^{-\frac{3}{2}} e^{-\Big[Ax+\frac{C}{x}\Bigr]}
$$

where
$$
A=3K\\
B=-2K(a+b+c)\\
C=K(a^2+b^2+c^2)
$$

Note that $A>0$, $C>0$ and critically, $B<0$ given the bounds on $K,a,b$ and $c$. For this form Wolfram yielded

[image]

which however is *potentially* problematic in terms of evaluation due to the resultant $e^{2\sqrt{AC}}$ term, given that $AC>0$. Looking at the original form of the integral, I was not expecting a term with a potentially large positive exponential argument, not to mention that the integral itself is now multiplied by another exponential term with a potentially large positive argument ($e^{-B}$ given $B<0$)

The alternate forms of the integral that Wolfram Alpha suggests do not help either

[image]

Now it turns out that for my particular case of interest, the magnitudes of $A$, $B$, and $C$ are not excessive (see the plot below), but I'm concerned about the general applicability of the expression. Is there a more robust form that can be constructed?

I did a sanity check of the integral with a quick-and-dirty trapezoidal rule and the two curves in the plot are graphically indistinguishable.

[image]

Comment: Damn! I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: I've restated the problem in response to what you pointed out, but there are persistent issues. I'm not able to reconcile the exponentials with positive arguments with the original form of the integral

Comment: It turns out that I may have been whining a bit much. I've added a plot to the post and the integral evaluates quite nicely for *my* particular case, but what if $A$, $B$, and $C$ are much larger in magnitude?

Comment: Right! For large arguments of the error function , the  term $\mathrm {erf}(z)-1$ decays at a faster rate than the growth of the exponential term $\exp{\sqrt{AC}}$, so all looks to be good. Many thanks again.